# IEEE 754 32 and 64 bit

Tags: numerical-methods, floating-point

I know that in each IEEE 754 number representation the number is in the format of $\text{sign}*\text{Exp}*1.\text{Mantissa}$.

In the case of 64 bit with have: 1 bit for the sign, 11 bits for the exponent and 52 for the mantissa, so where does $1$ (as each number starts 1.) is stored?

Comment: That bit is kept inside the head of the user of the float ;)

Comment: Note that it is $2^{\rm Exp}$ where the exponent is derived from the exponent bits with a bias subtracted. Or if the exponent bits are interpreted as signed int format, the mantissa interpretation is as $0.1{\rm Mantissa}$.